# How to use the ezsheets python module with Google Sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets

I am having trouble getting the ezsheets python module working. My code gives me an error `OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`

```
import ezsheets
ezsheets.listSpreadsheets()
```

I have obtained the credentials.json file and renamed it to credentials-sheets.json as required. The docs also specify

> Once you have a credentials-sheets.json file, run the import ezsheets
>   module. The first time you import the EZSheets module, it will open a
>   new browser window for you to log in to your Google account. Click
>   Allow.
>
> After you log in, the browser window will prompt you to close it, and
>   the token-sheets.pickle and token-drive.pickle files will appear in
>   the same folder as credentials-sheets.json. You only need to go
>   through this process the first time you run import ezsheets

However nothing happens even if I have a single line of code for `import ezsheets`. No pickle files are created and no browser window opens. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I pasted the json file into my current working directory and it worked! At first only the sheets permission was granted. I exited out of everything and tried again with 'import ezsheets' and that time it allowed me to grant access to google drive. Hope that helps.